# SMART hard disk check has detected an imminent failure

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, laptop, windows-error-reporting

Since two years ago I have this problem. I have a ***HP Pavilion dm4 Notebook PC***. Every time I turn on my laptop it comes a **black screen like this one**(I found it in Internet):

[image]

In this two years nothing have happened. Therefore, I would just like to know how to remove this screen, if it's possible, each time I boot my computer.

Comment: Back up the disk and replace it immediately. You cannot tell when it is going to fail. It could be in the next 10 minutes :/

Comment: If you can [make your HP recovery discs-flash drive](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01867124) before you replace the drive

Answer (score 2):

Your hard drive is indicating that it is failing. Although you have had two years of this, does not mean that space on the drive is not damaged, and the damage growing from being used to hold your data. It may be rewriting it to good sectors, until those sectors go bad and rewriting again.

You would most benefit from a new drive replacement. This will stop the error screen and maybe even boost performance if the drive has been doing a lot of rewriting.

Comment: I have another computer iMac. What exactly happens to my computer and hard disk if I don't change it? What does it mean **exactly** it has a failure(if it is more than just not working well)? I have 5 years with this laptop.

Comment: No one can answer this -  as @CarlB said - the hard disk thinks its failing, and should be replaced.   Modern disk drives use S.M.A.R.T to try and detect imminent failure.  It could be bad sectors, the head is out of alignment, inadequate lubrication, a whole list of things.  5 Years is a good life for a hard drive - you definately should be replacing it.

Comment: @davidgo Let's say that I don't have important things there and I can be without a computer for a while. Is there a way to take out that screen?

Comment: That depends on your BIOS.  Of-course, (I want to say if you don't have important things on it and can do without it, just remove the disk from the system altogether, but I guess that simply shows my intolerance for lack of maintenance !!)