# Did a Primary Hard Disk Self Test on my HP Pavilion dm4; what do these results mean?

Tags: hard-drive, smart, hp-pavilion, hard-drive-failure

I did a *Primary Hard Disk Self Test* and I would **want to know what the results mean.** I do know that my Hard Disk has failures...

My laptop is *HP Pavilion dm4*.

This is the [first screen picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dep8x.jpg) and this is the [second screen picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqMDM.jpg). The text from these are:

```
Primary Hard Disk Self Test
Quick test
Hard Disk 1 Fault......
Primary Hard Disk Self Test
Full test
  0% Complete  ....
Press <Esc> to Exit Testing
```

and

```
Primary Hard Disk Self Test
Quick test
Hard Disk 1 Fault......
Primary Hard Disk Self Test
Full Test
Hard Disk 1 Fault..
SMART check to Exit Testing
Hard Disk 1 SMART (301)

Press <ESC> to Continue
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Related question by the OP: [SMART hard disk check has detected an imminent failure](http://superuser.com/q/939373/53590)

Comment: It means your HDD's firmware has detected a hard failure, which means, you should replace your HDD.

Comment: Note that a SMART 301 error is non-standard and HP specific (Standard SMART attributes only go up to 255). I generally agree that you need to replace the disk, but as not all SMART errors are created equal (some indicate non-fatal but suboptimal conditions) you may want to contact HP (they have a nice Chat feature) to confirm.

Comment: @FrankThomas - I only suggest replacement because this type of error would be covered under HP's warranty.

Comment: @Ramhound, I completely agree. Contacting HP is the first step in the warentee replacement process, so our comments merge nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You are using Windows, You should run a [disk check](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/433-disk-check.html#post2010) then see if the message goes away and recheck with your HDD tests.

The 301 error code will be a Smart or Disk Self Test failure - in either case, it would indicate that the Hard Drive is failing and needs to be replaced.  It's impossible to estimate the remaining lifespan of the drive - it could carry on for a few months or fail tomorrow.

I would recommend replacing the Hard Drive yourself - it's a pretty straight forward procedure and will save the expense of paying someone else to do this.

You can check the [manual](http://www.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02615687.pdf) how to remove the Hard Drive on page 57.